# Using a very specifit part of an image

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to use this image. "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/middle/5-59028_image-single-line-border-clipart-dark-blue-swirl.png"

I don't need the background, just the blue line. is there a way I can get rid of the background? I've looked everywhere I feel like. any help would be greatly appreciated.

not sure if this is important, but it is going on a cover of a book, I'm using GMBinder and it will be placed on top of 2 other images.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with code. Since it's a solid color though, any image editor with the capability to select based on a single color should allow you to cut out just the blue line, and remove the non-transparent (fake) transparency grid. Photoshop, or GIMP, the latter being free, come to mind. There's also a few sites made specifically to remove this sort of background, like remove.bg.

Comment: thank you ill try photoshop